# Multiple movable objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite

I am trying to make a game that has five simple objects that the user can touch and move these have physics on them but having trouble getting them to move separately any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let starSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "starSprite")
    let circleSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circleSprite")
    let squareSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "squareSprite")
    let triangleSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangleSprite")
    let moonSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "moonSprite")

    var touchLocation = CGPoint()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        layoutScene()
    }

    func layoutScene() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 62/255, blue: 
        80/255, alpha: 1.0)

        starSprite.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        starSprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        starSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
        starSprite.texture!, size: starSprite.size)

         addChild(starSprite)

        circleSprite.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        circleSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        circleSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
        circleSprite.texture!, size: circleSprite.size)
        addChild(circleSprite)

        squareSprite.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        squareSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)
        squareSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
        squareSprite.texture!, size: squareSprite.size)
        addChild(squareSprite)

        triangleSprite.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        triangleSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300)
        triangleSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
        triangleSprite.texture!, size: triangleSprite.size)
        addChild(triangleSprite)

        moonSprite.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        moonSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 400)
        moonSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
        moonSprite.texture!, size: moonSprite.size)
        addChild(moonSprite)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            moonSprite.position.x = (touchLocation.x)
            moonSprite.position.y = (touchLocation.y)
            starSprite.position.x = (touchLocation.x)
            starSprite.position.y = (touchLocation.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first detect which object has been selected in touchDown, then change the position in touchesMoved, and release the object in touchUp!

define a value as a temp and use that!

In addition , and you don't need to use this

```
moonSprite.position.x = (touchLocation.x)
moonSprite.position.y = (touchLocation.y)
```

it's better

```
 moonSprite.position = touchLocation
```

Edited Code

```
    //
//  GameScene.swift
//  aa
//
//  Created by ehsan on 1/30/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ehsan. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var spinnyNode1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
    private var spinnyNode2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "2")
    private var movingSprite:SKSpriteNode?



    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        addChild(spinnyNode1)
        addChild(spinnyNode2)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for t in touches {

            let location = t.location(in: self)
            let node = self.atPoint(location)
            if node is SKSpriteNode
            {
                movingSprite = node as? SKSpriteNode
            }


        }

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if movingSprite != nil

            {

                movingSprite!.position = touchLocation
            }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        movingSprite = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {



        }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ehsan I am really new at this could you elaborate

Comment: Thanks that works still having trouble but it must be the size on the physics body

Comment: the sprites don't always pick up correctly sometimes your trying to move one and it grabs another or picks up two at once.

Comment: Actually, I only showed how to do it, but you should do manage your sprites! it was only the algorithm!  but I've edited the post, and it works more efficiently!